# Associating a list with polygons?

Tags: shapefile, polygon, spatial-join, list

I have a shapefile with different polygons (basins) and a table with a list of species indicating the polygon name where they belong. I would like to know if there is any way to associate the shapefile and the list of species, in order to be capable of retrieving the list of species when I visualize the polygons in ArcGIS or QGIS.

Comment: Create pivot table in Excel, using polygon I'd as rows, species as columns, count as value. Bring table to arcgis and join it to basins. Export result to geodatabase to keep species names as field aliases

Answer (score 1):

If the shapefile and the table share a common attribute, you may use the **Join attribute table** algorithm in QGIS (available from the Processing Toolbox).

The result should be a new vector which stores both the geometries and the attributes in the same layer.

Comment: What if more than 1 specie belong to the same polygon?

Comment: @FelixIP I assumed that the *list of species* belongs to a unique field in the table (i.e. the list is a whole attribute, as it seems from the original question). Otherwise, there could be problems, but the OP didn't add too many details to his question.